# Electric displacement field $D$ - what do the terms in the definition represent intuitively?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

In the following equation I would like to check what the terms represent intuitively (in a hand-wavey sense - I know $\underline{D}$ is not a physical thing so it's not possible to fully describe it in a physical way):

$$\underline{D}=\epsilon_0 \underline{E}+\underline{P}$$

Am I correct with the following?

$\underline{D}$:  The electric field without the effects of any fields produced within the material (which will have a shift in charge induced by the external field, and will produce its own electric field which cancels part of the external field). Describes just the effects of the free charges (which create the external field)

$\epsilon_0 \underline{E}$: Includes the effects of the external field and the induced internal field in the materials. Should be smaller than D. Is a combination of the effects of the free and bound charges.

$\underline{P}$: Includes the effects of the fields from internal (bound) charges only.

[I have read contradictory explanations (incl. on stack exchange) that $\epsilon_0 \underline{E}$ represents just the effects of the free charge, with $\underline{E}$ being just the external electric field rather than a combination of external and internal. And that $\underline{D}$ represents the effects of the free + the bound charge. - am I wrong and are these correct instead?]

[I was also confused thinking the equation should be:  $\underline{D}=\epsilon_0 \underline{E}-\underline{P}$ ie.  [external = (internal + external) - internal]  if my term definitions were correct, but in writing the question I have figured out that the electric field due to $\underline{P}$ points the opposite direction to $\underline{P}$, so that works out ok!]

Comment: $\vec{E}$ is what the field would be free space if no material was present. $\vec{P}$ is the field created by the material in response to $\vec{E}$. Since electric fields are additive, you get a net field $\vec{D}$ which is the sum of the two.

Comment: @CasualScience The polarization density $\vec{P}$ is parallel to $\vec{E}$ so it can't be interpreted as the response to $\vec{E}$.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas What? From Feynman: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html 

"The only thing that is essential to the understanding of dielectrics is that there are many little dipoles induced in the material [...] This dipole moment per unit volume will be represented by a vector, P."

Comment: @CasualScience Yes, correct for the induced dipoles. But the polarization density has the direction of dipole moments which is parallel to the applied field. The direction of the induced field (which reduces the electric field inside the material) is antiparallel to the applied field.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Okay, so it's defined with a minus sign, I was giving the intuition. At least say that's what you mean and don't act like the entire idea is wrong.

Comment: @CasualScience Apologize if my comment sound like that. I wanted to put emphasis on the idea that $P$ is not the response to the $E$ field because then someone would say that the net field inside the material is $\vec{D} = ε_0\vec{E}  + \vec{P}$, which isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably fair to say that inside a macroscopic piece of matter neither the field $\mathbf{E}$ nor $\mathbf{D}$ is more real than the other. Both are $macroscopic$ mathematical constructs and both can be measured by using Kelvin's crevices.

As you well know both $E$ and $D$ jump at the interface of two different dielectrics (or dielectric/vacuum) in such a way that the tangential component of the $E$ field and the normal component of the $D$ field stay continuous, resp. Consequently, if you make a long thin needle like crevice (much thinner than long) that is parallel with the field $\mathbf{E}$ then inside the crevice the $E_t$ being tangential to the needle will be the same as in the dielectric. Similarly, if you prepare a very thin disk shaped crevice that is perpendicular to the local $\mathbf{D}$ then within the crevice $D_n=\epsilon_0 E_n$ will be the same as just outside it. So both $E_t$ in the needle and $D_n$ in the disk are physically measurable, at least in principle.

The source that generates these fields are charges both microscopic and macroscopic. The divergence of $\mathbf{D}$ is the so-called free charges, essentially the ones we can observe macroscopically: $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \rho$. From the definition $$\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P} \tag{1}\label{1}$$ you have $$\epsilon_0 \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \rho - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}\tag{2}\label{2}$$ which tells you the divergence of $\mathbf{E}$ is both from the free charges $\rho$ and from the bound charges $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$.

But remember that the divergence by itself does not determine a vector field, you also need its circulation (curl). In statics we know that $$\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$, therefore $$\nabla \times \mathbf{D}= \nabla \times \mathbf{P}\tag{4}\label{4}$$

There is another way to see what this all means using the Helmholtz decomposition theorem [1] according to which any smooth vector field $\mathbf{F}$ can be represented as 
$$\mathbf{F}= -\nabla {\Phi} +\nabla\times\mathbf{A}\tag{5}\label{5}$$
where
$$ \Phi(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\nabla'\cdot \mathbf{F(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV' \\
\mathbf{A(\mathbf{r})} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\nabla' \times \mathbf{F(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV' \tag{6}\label{6}$$

Apply this to the polarization vector $\mathbf{P}$:

$$ \mathbf{P} = -\nabla\cdot \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\nabla'\cdot \mathbf{P(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV' + \nabla \times \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\nabla' \times \mathbf{P(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV'$$
or introducing the $E^*$ and $D^*$ fields we get
$$\mathbf{E^*}= \nabla\cdot \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \frac{\nabla'\cdot \mathbf{P(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV'\\
\mathbf{D^*}= \nabla \times \frac{1}{4\pi}\int \frac{\nabla' \times \mathbf{P(\mathbf{r'})}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}dV' \tag{8}\label{8}$$
Note that both integrals can be restricted to the volume of the dielectric where $P\ne 0$

Given the polarization $\mathbf{P}$ the fields $\mathbf{E^*}$ and $\mathbf{D^*}$ are determined, and indeed one can justifiably say that the polarization are the source of both. Now if we have an external $static$ bias field say $\mathbf{E_0}$ and wish to calculate the field distribution resulting from it then we can write
$$\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E_0}+ \mathbf{E^*} \\
\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0\mathbf{E_0}+ \mathbf{D^*} \tag{9}\label{9}$$